# Vote to Close with different reasons make it seem like you agree with majority reason

Tags: discussion, closing-questions

In the case of [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/35288/roll20-reminded-me-of-a-similar-program-help-me-identify-it), there were 3 VTC based on it being a duplicate, 1 VTC based on it being opinion based, and 1 VTC (mine) based on the question being unclear.

It was closed as a duplicate; though it had been discussed in the comments about it being unclear, and one of the possible clarifications making it a duplicate, it seems that what we're communicating in this case (and in many other cases) might be different from what the problem actually is, based on nothing other than a majority vote.

I have no problem with that, it just struck me in this case that this is what we're doing, and wanted to clarify that this is actually what we meant by the VTC system.

Comment: I have this problem with the result of a VTC too. I'd like to see a note about what the dissenting opinions were in the close banner.